# Why does VS Code use a different Terminal than the standard Mac Terminal and how do I change it?

Tags: macos, sass, terminal, visual-studio-code

I just installed Dart Sass with the intention of replacing Ruby Sass, which is deprecated.

Now when I check the version of Sass using the Terminal in Visual Studio Code, I get `Ruby Sass 3.7.3`:

[image: Ruby Sass 3.7.3]

But when I check the version of Sass in a regular Terminal window, I get `1.20.1 compiled with dart2js 2.2.0`:

[image: 1.20.1 compiled with dart2js 2.2.0]

Why is this different and how do I get VS Code to use the same settings as the main terminal?

In case it's helpful, my terminal setting in VS Code is `/bin/bash/`:

[image]

Also, in case it's helpful, when I echo $PATH at the two different terminals, I get different results.

Comment: the key here is `$PATH`. the terminal emulator is moot.

Comment: @BradAllred, can you expand on that? What should I be looking for in my path?

Comment: it's not about a specific something in `$PATH`. it's that in Unix when you execute a command it searches the paths in `$PATH` in order until it finds a match. In the VS code case you clearly have some path in the environment built by VS that is causing `sass` to resolve to a different binary than Terminal.app

Comment: both powershell and Terminal.app will use bash by default. look for "environment" or "profile" settings in VS (something to alter `$PATH`).

Comment: @BradAllred, thanks, but I don't see anything like that in my setting.json. No environment or profile settings and nothing to do with Ruby or Sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this problem by uninstalling Ruby Sass:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
```

I still don't understand how VS Code was using a different version of Sass in its terminal, but at least this is resolved.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem like you fully answered your own question (but you accepted your entry as the answer).